# How to pass `lambda: pass` as keyword argument?

Tags: python, lambda, keyword-argument

Passing lambda as keyword argument can be done easily as

```
def foo(bar=lambda x: x):
    pass
```

I want a None->None lambda as a default:

```
def foo(bar=lambda: pass):
    pass
```

but getting

```
    def foo(bar=lambda: pass):
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to pass a None->None lambda as a default keyword argument?

Comment: `pass`, I think doesn't provide a functional object so you can use it as a return from the lambda

Comment: I think that @quamrana's answer is appropriate for what I *guess* you want, but I'm still somewhat confused by your requirement. A function mapping ``None -> None`` is equivalent to your initial``lambda x: x`` or ``lambda x: None``. The closest to ``lambda: pass`` might be a a function mapping ``() -> None`` as ``lambda: None``, or a function mapping ``() -> void `` which cannot exist in Python.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You are correct, I want to map `()` to `None`, but I don't understand what can't exist?

Comment: What I *want* is a default argument which is an anonymous function that in essence takes in nothing and outputs nothing.

Comment: @Gulzar That's perfectly fine! I just wanted to double–check since "nothing", "`None`" and "`pass`" often are erroneously treated as equivalent by people. Anyways, glad someone could help you quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pass` is a statement, whereas a lambda can only contain one expression (effectively, it's a function whose only line is a `return`, and the body of the lambda is the thing that's returned).

In Python, when you reach the end of a function without an explicit return (or when you have an explicit return without specifying something to return), it returns `None`. So a function

```
def foo():
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
def foo():
    return None
```

So you can write this as a lambda that returns `None`:

```
lambda: None
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `pass` is not a synonym for `return None`. So perhaps return `None` instead?

```py
def foo(bar=lambda: None):
    pass
```

Comment: Perhaps you can drop the perhaps? ;)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Which one? :-)